# How to find the line with the error in Template Toolkit files?

Tags: perl, exception, error-handling, template-engine

`print $@` for template toolkit does not show the line where the exception occurred. How to find the exact place of the error?

```
$ perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -MTemplate -e 'my $template = Template->new({ABSOLUTE=>0}); $template->process("test.tt") || print $@, "\n"'
file error - /etc/hosts: absolute paths are not allowed (set ABSOLUTE option)
```

I do not see which line of the `.tt` file caused the error. This makes debugging difficult.

Why does TT not show the location of the error? Is it an inherent problem of a feature which is hard to implement? If not, why is it yet not implemented? Should I propose bug report to implement this feature?

Comment: I would think a simple search through the `.tt` file looking for `/etc/hosts` would suffice.

Comment: @JimGarrison In this particular case, yes. But I want a method of easily locating errors when there are many files structured with `[% INCLUDE %]` directives and it is unknown where to search the offending file

Comment: This is probably helpful http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=605410

Comment: @JimGarrison No, the link you suggested is on an entirely orthogonal topic, it does not describe how to locate the line of the error, but just how to display errors (without the line information)

Comment: Does `$template->error()` not show the line number?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot It does not show the line number :-(

Comment: Weirdly enough it does not show error location for `file error`, but works well (shows line numbers) for such things as unclosed `[% IF %]` directive. I will report a bug

Comment: (`$@` is set by `eval BLOCK`, `eval EXPR` and `do EXPR`, but you don't use any of those. There's no reason to believe `$@` is meaningful. Please use `$template->error()` as documented.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug. Thanks for [reporting](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=112022) it.